# Inventory System Class Layout

Tags: c#, oop, class, xna

Im making an inventory system for my game. Im not quite sure on how the structure of the classes should be, I already have a weapons, items, and blocks class. Weapons go on the player, Items can be placed on blocks, and blocks can be placed on a tile grid. I have a class called tile to handle placing on the grid. But im wondering how I should make  a class to hold each 'thing' together ('things' being, weapons,blocks, and items).

If im unclear or you need more information just comment.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Why does each thing need to be held together?  It seems like you already have the relationships in place.  A player has weapons.  Tiles contain blocks which contain items.

Comment: What common functionality do they have?  Is there something that needs to have an item that could be any one of those things?  If so, what will it need to do with it?  My guess is you want an interface that defines all of the common behavior between those 'things'.  If there is none, you need no interface.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KxirPZR4 This is what i have, I can assign tiles with tiles[x,y] = new Tile("Blah.Arguments here...."), but I want to be able to make an inventory system, of what blocks,weapons, items  I have. I know this is probably simple but for some reason im having a hard time doing/explaining it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a good starting idea, but think out of the box - if you have a typical inventory then you got

Player
+ Inventory
  + [] Items
+ [] Weapons

If you plan to implement a slot based inventory, then you have many possibilities to realize the item-binding, e.g.
1) Item placed in Slot in Inventory
2) Item placed in Item in Slot in Inventory
3) Item placed in Inventory in Inventory (e.g. a Chest or sth. else)

So try to think about a concept which is more flexible - you could do this by creating some interfaces or provider classes which are able to hold other things. A way could be

Player got Inventory
Inventory implements IInventory
Item implements IInventory (if it is a Chest or sth. else)

If you wanna implement such a grid we know from WoW or so, then you also could write classes which are able to sort and order items...

Inventory implements IOrderedInventory

and your Grid offers an IInventoryAdapter

By handling your actions and classes these ways, you can be sure, that the interconnection works fine.

I hope i was able to give you some ideas.

Greetings,